# Unable to boot linux from USB CF card reader on vmware

Tags: linux, boot, vmware

I have a CF card that has Red hat linux installed on it and its booting fine on actual PC. Now I need to boot a virtual machine from this CF card. I have tried to connect it to vmware workstation virtual machine and tried booting from this card using Plop boot manager (as described on this website: https://www.howtogeek.com/97923/how-to-boot-a-vmware-virtual-machine-from-a-usb-drive/). But I am not able to fully boot from this card. Following error is occurred and boot process stops on this error:

[image]

Please guide me how to resolve this error. I am very new to Linux, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using plop, have you tried booting directly from the USB device by configuring the VM to use a UEFI firmware?

Comment: @jamesdlin, thanks for your comment. The OS is very old (from around 2004) and might not support modern UEFI protocol. Also the version of VMware workstation 15 doesn't seem to have the option to boot directly from USB device.

Comment: my first guess is a /etc/fstab issue, does the usb filesystem have a fstab? what does it contain?

Comment: Please add to you post the version of the host, guest and VMware that you are using and the computer model.

Comment: Perhaps you can try configuring a VM to boot from the CF card as a physical disk?

Comment: @jamesdlin yes.

Comment: Yes what?  Yes you can try?  Yes you did try?  If so, what happened?  Did you use it as an IDE disk?

Comment: Very old you say. Did it originally support USB booting? Does it have drivers for the USB version VMware Player emulates? Are these drivers in the initial ramdisk/initramfs?

Answer (score 2):

The operating system on your CompactFlash card is most likely not USB-bootable. When put inside a PC, the CompactFlash card appears as a regular IDE hard drive. You put it in a CF card reader so it now appears as a USB mass storage device. This requires different kernel drivers (USB, USB Controller, USB Mass Storage) that this “very old” system may either not have at all or at least not in the *initrd*.

Going forward, you have two options:

- Update the *initrd* so it contains all the drivers required boot from a USB mass storage device
- Add the CF card to your VM as a virtual IDE drive using disk passthrough

You may also want to take an image of the CF card, making both options easier as well as letting you keep the original system unmodified.

---

The output you see means the Linux kernel + *initrd* booted correctly up until the point where the *initrd* code is supposed to find a partition labeled `/`.

Answer (score 1):

As some others said, the Red Hat from almost 20 years ago probably cannot boot from USB. Considering the "Red Hat nash 3.4.42" output, it seems you do have Red Hat Linux 9 (from 31 March 2003).
As far as I can tell, PCs could boot from USB only around 2005 and later.

Some suggested the right thing, which is using the Compact Flash as a raw disk, or even better: Clone the whole compact flash to a .vmdk to make things easier (you can make this by booting any Linux live CD in your VM as long as you correctly use the dd command, please do it).

Do note that 2003 was when IDE was the main boot type along SCSI, and when SATA just got released (but that shouldn't matter as SATA was still backed by IDE then).
So for you to have better chances to sort things out, just put your raw Compact Flash as an IDE drive, and if it still doesn't work as an SCSI drive.
However, the IDE/SCSI's controller may foul things, so you'll have to try with either BusLogic or LSILogic (LSILogic was already popular at that time) controllers on VMWare.

Also, it's rather unusual to have such server distribution on a Compact Flash.

Since you're very new to Linux, I do think that either you made a ghost/raw copy of the original drive, or that someone gave you the Compact Flash as is.

In either cases, please ensure that you do have the whole operating system on your Compact Flash with every partitions needed (mostly /boot and /), and that the operating system wasn't being part of something that could have scattered the partitions (RAID array, multi-drives, etc), which could increase risks of improper drive cloning. You'll have to sort that out before we can help you more.

Now, if you did clone your Compact Flash to a .vmdk, you can now snapshot the VM and then safely explore your .vmdk with a Live CD and see if you do have a proper / partition.

Sometimes, the filesystem may be damaged. I don't how many years the Compact Flash wasn't being used or powered on, but if it did for let's say more than 10 years, the filesystem may have suffered bit rot. In any case, just try an fsck on that drive to see if it does work, but since it's ext2 you may probably not recover from that.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you select the right option to boot from in the menu:
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-EAAE9426-D08E-4DF1-820B-7C022C2A85FA.html

Procedure

1. Right-click a virtual machine in the inventory and select Edit Settings.
2. Click VM Options tab and expand Boot Options.
3. In the Boot Delay section, select the time in milliseconds to delay the boot operation.
4. (Optional) In the Force setup section, select whether to force entry into the BIOS or EFI setup screen the next time the virtual machine boots.
5. (Optional) In the Failed Boot Recovery section, select whether the virtual machine should reboot after a boot failure and enter the time in seconds.
6. Click OK.

While I do think someone may find these steps helpful, it looks like my additional comment is the actual answer. VMWare doesn't allow you to boot directly to a USB Drive. There is some additional configuration required. Please see my other comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think the doc is the answer. The question honestly was convoluted. It should read "How do I select the boot options for VMWare'. I will re do my comment. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what that would accomplish. The VM boot successfully. It’s just that the Linux kernel cannot find the root filesystem that it is supposed to find.

Comment: Daniel, It is only booting to BIOS though. You are searching for the Operating System. My guess is you need to tell the BIOS where it is. It looked for Floppy first. Didn't find it. Good luck..

Comment: Daniel, I reviewed the link you sent. This is a step. It is just they suggest you do it during startup. Here is a link to the screenshot in the steps you provided that I think provides you with the answer. 
https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/101.png?trim=1,1&bg-color=000&pad=1,1

Comment: In the screenshot OP provides it is unambiguous that Linux has started. The boot configuration is okay. The operating system is not.